# Multiple users are not connecting in WebRtc using RtcPeerConnection

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr, webrtc, signalr-hub

I am working on video conferencing tool, here i need to create a room where we can connect with multiple users for videoChat..

The simulation of what happens exactly as follow:

Let say we have 3 peers A, B, and C, the connections created from A to B and from A to C is normal and work correctly but the problem happens when B trying to connect C, that makes the connection A-C disconnected

in a technical way: in connections, A-B and A-C iceConnectionState flag be completed but when B connected to C, A-C connection iceConnectionState flag change to disconnected then after moment change again to checking and still in this state. I don't know why this interruption happening and how can I resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what have you tried so far, what specifically is going wrong, and do you have a minimal working example of the issue? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: currently i am able to do peer to peer conection. but now need to create a group for video call to multiple users in single time. is there any suggesstion?